# cant append text node to element using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, nodes

im trying to get some data from another html page and create an element in javascript and then added it to the dom
so far im trying to append a text node inside an h1 and p element from a variable
the console shows this error

```
script.js:32 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
at script.js:32:7
```

this is the code i will add some comments to clarify :

```
window.addEventListener("load",() =>{
const data = (new URL (document.location)).searchParams;
// all of these are strings 
const title = data.get('title'); 
const desc = data.get('desc');
const date = data.get("date");
const PDF = data.get("pdf");
// elmenet creation
const columns = document.createElement("div");
const worksheetCon=document.createElement("div");
const card = document.createElement("div");
const imageDiv = document.createElement("div");
const image = document.createElement("img");
const h1 = document.createElement("h1");
// creating h1 elment text node to append it later to h1 element
const h1Text = document.createTextNode(title);
const contain = document.createElement("div");
const p =document.createElement("p");
// creating p elment text node to append it later to append it later to p element
const Ptext = document.createTextNode(desc);
// trying to figure out type of text node it says its object
alert(typeof Ptext);
worksheetCon.className = "container-worksheets";
columns.className = "columns";
card.className = "carde";
imageDiv.className = "img";
contain.className = "contain";
worksheetCon.appendChild(columns);
columns.appendChild(card);
card.appendChild(imageDiv);
imageDiv.appendChild(image);
card.appendChild(h1);
h1.appendChild(h1Text)
card.appendChild(contain);
contain.appendChild(p);
p.appendChild(Ptext );
const worksheets = document.querySelector("worksheets");
worksheets.appendChild(card);
```

})

Comment: I don't see you ever using `Ptext`. Also, you should declare your variables.

Comment: i tested it first with h1text

Comment: Are you sure that this is the line where you get the error?

Comment: yes im sure i shared the error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: thats all the code ignore what is not relevant

Comment: what im trying to do is create a text node from a variable and append it inside and h1 element that i created in js

Comment: The error gives you a source line number where it occurred., Line 32 of the post is `32┊card.appendChild(h1);`, but card was used successfully several times before. So what line generated the error?

Answer (score 0):

As I said, you never use `Ptext`, but you try to use `desc` as a `Node`

```
const desc = data.get('desc');
p.appendChild(desc);
```

Comment: i know bruh i changed now + there is another variable h1text that has the same problem